# How do I determine the maximum range for perl's range iterator?

Tags: perl, int, range, limit

I can exceed perl's range iteration bounds like so, with or without `-Mbigint`:

```
$» perl -E 'say $^V; say for (0..shift)' 1e19
v5.16.2
Range iterator outside integer range at -e line 1.
```

How can I determine this upper limit, without simply trying until I exceed it?

Comment: try (2**31)-1 or (2**63)-1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's an IV.

`>>` similarly works on integers, so you can use

```
my $max_iv = -1 >> 1;
my $min_iv = -(-1 >> 1) - 1;
```

They can also be derived from the size of an IV.

```
my $max_iv = (1 << ($iv_bits-1)) - 1;
my $min_iv = -(1 << ($iv_bits-1));
```

The size of an IV can be obtained using

```
use Config qw( %Config );
my $iv_bits = 8 * $Config{ivsize};
```

or

```
my $iv_bits = 8 * length pack 'j', 0;
```